# Symfony | Authenticate request

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, symfony4

I'm trying to create a "service" like application, which can be able to receive API calls from another services. (These services will be built, for different purposes). And also able to send API calls to an another one.

Each request that they send, and accept has to have the following format.

```
{
    header : {
        // some header information, like locale, currency code etc.
        signature : "some-hashed-data-using-the-whole-request"
    },
    request : {
        // the usable business data
    }
}
```

To each request I want to append a hash, that is generated from the actual request or anyhow (salted with password or any kind of magic added). Its not that important at the moment. I gave the name `signature` to this field. So for each received request, I want to reproduce this `signature` from the request. If the `signature` I received is matching with the one I generated, I let the application run otherwise showing some error message.

I already read a few articles, but most of them is for user-pass combinations.

My question is not about that if it's a good solution or not. I just want to know how can implement a middleware like functionality - like in laravel - in Symfony 4?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If not, can you please provide a comment telling what is unclear? Otherwise, please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Did you read up on [before and after filters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)?

Comment: I started with the [API Key Authentication](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html) site, but i'll check that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As k0pernikus mentioned, the [before after filters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting headers into a JSON object the HTTP body, use HTTP headers directly. That’s what they are for. When you’re using non-standard headers, prefix them with `X-` and maybe a prefix for your application, for example `X-YourApp-Signature`. The request goes into the body, i.e. the value of the `request` property in your example.

The server side is pretty simple with Symfony:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $signature = $request->headers->get("X-YourApp-Signature");
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

    // ... go on processing the received values (validation etc.)
}
```

If you want to write a HTTP client application in PHP, I would recommend using the [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org) library. Here’s an example:

```
$headers = ["X-YourApp-Signature" => "your_signature_string"];
$data = json_encode(["foo" => "bar"]);
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request("POST", "https://example.com", $headers, $data);
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->send($request, ["timeout" => 10]);
var_dump($response);
```

Of course, you’ll also want to implement some error handling etc. (HTTP status >= 400), so the code will be a bit more complex in a real application.

Comment: I know that I can put this signature into the header also. At this point its not important. I also know about the Guzzle, but that is also not my question. 

The point is, that I should not do this "authentication" in the controller, and copy-paste this authentication to all other controller that I'll have. Or copy-paste a method call. I should have implement some kind of a middleware before any controller method will be called. Same like in Laravel.

Comment: Then you should maybe clarify your question.